# how to create image from gis data in C#

Tags: c#, image, sql-server-2008, gis, geospatial

I'm using C# to pull spatial data from a sql server 2008 database.  I'm then trying to perform operations on that data, but to start... I want to be able to visualize it.  That is, I would like to create an image of the data, preferably in jpg format.

I thought that I might do it by hand, but that is proving more challenging than I had originally thought that it would, given that the degrees are not whole numbers, and I can't just truncate them to draw onto a graphics object.

Can someone point me to the right library that might help me to perform this operation?

NOTE:  Paying for a library is not an option for me, at this time.

Comment: Ouch. I briefly looked into this at home, for curiosity reasons.  I didn't come up with a good answer. I'm interested in seeing what you - or the community - come up with!

From your stated goals I think you should step back and say Goal 1 - Draw the image.  Goal 2 - save as jpg. There are plenty of articles online that teach you goal 2 for any arbitrary image drawn in memory.  Goal 1 is going to be the tough one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to create images in your program using C# or if you just want to see some images in any way possible outside of your program (you didn't state either way). If you just want a stand alone GUI for doing this, there is [QuantumGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) which is free and can visually represent GIS data for you. It was invaluable for me when I started figuring out geospatial data, it looks like this:

[alt text http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/resource/qgis1.png](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/resource/qgis1.png)

You could also use the [SqlSpatial tool from SharpGIS](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SqlSpatial-Query-Tool.aspx):

[image]
<sub>(source: [bostongis.com](http://www.bostongis.com/images/snippets/sql2008_sqlspatialviewplanar.png))</sub>

Comment: From looking at the brochure on QGIS v1.3, it could suite my needs.  I'll have to do some examples and try to utilize the qgis core library.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can export the data to google earth. The API also allows you to take screenshots programatically.

Answer (score 0):

- [GDAL](https://gdal.org/)

A translator library for raster and vector geospatial data formats that is released under an X/MIT style Open Source license by the Open Source Geospatial Foundation. As a library, it presents a single raster abstract data model and single vector abstract data model to the calling application for all supported formats. It also comes with a variety of useful command line utilities for data translation and processing. The NEWS page describes the January 2017 GDAL/OGR 2.1.3 release.

- [Read/Write API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/vector_api_tut.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap) to view or export GIS data.
It is native C# and doesn´t have many dependencies.